# Dynamic wallpaper .jpg from internet - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

I would like to set my wallpaper as an image with a fixed URL from the internet. Every day the image gets updated, keeping exactly the same URL, name and location.

Is there a way to do this in Windows 10? If not with wallpapers, maybe with the lock screen?